# Troubles installing nvidia driver on 18.04 fresh install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

I installed the nvidia drivers using the `Software & Updates` GUI. Alas, when trying to install [Nvidia docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) I realized that something was not working:

```
ignacio@ignacio-XPS-8930:~$ nvidia-smi -a
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA 
driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

This screenshot shows that ubuntu is telling me that the nvidia driver is installed

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: I have to disable it and keep it disabled? Can you point me to some instructions?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a proprietary driver, you need to keep Secure Boot disabled. Run `sudo modprobe nvidia` and see https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255

Comment: That did the trick. @Pilot6, should I delete this question or do you want to enter an answer?