# Unable to install Nvidia driver on Ubuntu 18.04 on xps 15 9570

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

I have been struggling with installing nvidia driver on Ubuntu 18.04 on xps 15 9570.

My first attempt is to install it through apt-get. Yet, after installation nvidia-smi still suggests that i did not install the driver.

After that, I tried to follow the recipe for installing on 16.04 on the same machine at [1], yet, the problem persist.

May I ask how can I solve this problem?

[1] #28 in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2392938&page=3

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053282/troubles-installing-nvidia-driver-on-18-04-fresh-install

Comment: I have tried that. The problem still persist and I can't even boot into ubuntu after disable it.

Comment: You probably disable UEFI boot, not secure boot. Disabling SB can't affect booting.

Comment: After i disable secure boot with mokutil and installed the nvidia-driver-390, the nvidia-smi output is still the same and the booting screen is stucked in Started GNOME Display Mode.

Comment: I have tried to install the driver through Nvidia run script downloaded from their website. After installation, nvidia-smi shows reasonable output. Yet when I reboot, the pc stucked at the same place as before.

Comment: Turns out I am able to install it through ubuntu software & updates (in the additional driver section).

Comment: Check out my blog post here - https://medium.com/@pwaterz/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-15-inch-dell-xps-9570-with-nvidia-1050ti-gpu-4b9a2901493d

Comment: Check out my blog post here - https://medium.com/@pwaterz/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-15-inch-dell-xps-9570-with-nvidia-1050ti-gpu-4b9a2901493d I had ton of issue getting the driver working. The main thing that fixed a lot the issue was updating the kernel.